# How to get private key from PKCS#12 (.p12) file using C#

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate2, pkcs#12

Im trying to sign some data using PKCS#12 certificate ,however i have problem with obtaining private key from PKCS#12 (.p12) file.

```
    public byte[] sign(string text)
    {
        string password = "1111";
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\certificate.p12",password);
        byte[] certData = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx,password);

        X509Certificate2 newCert = new X509Certificate2(certData, password);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider crypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)newCert.PrivateKey;

        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
        return crypt.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
    }
```

The problem is that newCert.PrivateKey is null but if i am using .pfx certicitae in similar way it works.

```
    public byte[] sign(string text)
    {
        string password = "1234";
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\certificate.pfx", password);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider crypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
        return crypt.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
    }
```

So the question is how to get that private key from .p12 file ?

Comment: Have you tried the same code for both the .PFX and the .P12? Depending on where you got your P12 from, it's supposed to be quite the same I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178711/c-exception-when-trying-to-read-a-privatekey-from-windows-certstore), although it is not the same thing for you, the problem may be also permissions.
My suggestions are, first, you have to make sure (which I suppose you already did) that the private key is exportable and you have permissions to the file.
Next, try exporting the content type as `X509ContentType.Pkcs12` instead of `X509ContentType.Pfx`
Finally, if it is possible, why don't you try importing it to the certstore. I believe that's more secure. The steps are in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for te answer. Permissions are not a problem, same with non exportable key. I tried changing type to `X509ContentType.Pkcs12` but with the same result. Altough importing this to certstore could be a sollution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826321/how-can-constructing-an-x509certificate2-from-a-pkcs12-byte-array-throw-cryptogr). It looks very similar.

Comment: Hi @Timores. Thanks for the link but solution from that question isn't working for me apparently.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ww6yzk.aspx), it says that `.export()` doesn't support the `Pfx` type, only `Cert`, `SerializedCert`, and `Pkcs12`.

Answer (score -1):

This was done for using Android - so the R.raw.key below was my file in the Android Raw folder.

I opened key.p12 as as input stream. Which I then converted to the private key using the libraries as seen in the example.

http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleSMIMEsign.html

My code looks like this

```
Security.addProvider(new de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider());
    // Next, we have to read the private PKCS #12 file, since the the
    // private key used for signing is contained in this file:
    DERDecoder dec = new DERDecoder(getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.key));
    PFX pfx = new PFX();
    try {
        pfx.decode(dec);
        SafeBag safeBag = pfx.getAuthSafe().getSafeContents(0)
                .getSafeBag(0);
        PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag kBag = (PKCS8ShroudedKeyBag) safeBag
                .getBagValue();
        char[] password = "my password for the p12".toCharArray();
        privKey = kBag.getPrivateKey(password);
        new AsyncLoadStorage(this).execute();
    } catch (ASN1Exception e) {
```

Comment: I believe its in Java. When i wrote that program i need it to do this in C# but thanks for sharing this.