# Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Keyset does not exist in IIS7 application hosted in windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Getting error when access an application hosted in IIS7 in Windows server 2008 R2.

Error: 
Exception Source: mscorlib:ListFunctions_LoadNamePrefixes()
Stack Trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetSignatureFormatter(String algorithm)
   at System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature(SecurityKey signingKey)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CompletePrimarySignatureCore(SendSecurityHeaderElement[] signatureConfirmations, SecurityToken[] signedEndorsingTokens, SecurityToken[] signedTokens, SendSecurityHeaderElement[] basicTokens)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CreateSupportingSignature(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifier identifier)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingToken(SecurityToken token, SecurityKeyIdentifierClause identifierClause)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingTokens()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

The certificate is stored in Trusted root.
The certificate is accessed by X509Store in the code.
The application is asp.net application.

Comment: Same stack trace in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178711/492336

Answer (score 1):

Certificate should be placed in LocalMachine\My store (Personal store in Local computer when viewed in mmc). Certificate chain should be able to build and should be valid.

Set rights on private key corresponding to the certificate.

The name of the account that you need to add permission for is **IIS APPPOOL\name_of_the_apppool_your_app_runs_under**

Comment: Run command `certutil -store My`. It will check all certificates in LocalMachine\My store. It will try to encrypt and decrypt to check if private key is available.

Comment: Certificate is kept in trusted root